# how to get accurate days after spliting in date according to financial yr in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I split two dates "10-Jun-2016" and "09-Jun-2019" into below date ranges:

```
10-Jun-2016 31-Mar-2017 294
01-Apr-2017 31-Mar-2018 364
01-Apr-2018 31-Mar-2019 364
01-Apr-2019 09-Jun-2019 69
```

If I total the number of days difference then it comes 1091, but if I take days difference of this two dates "10-Jun-2016" and "09-Jun-2019" it comes 1094.

How can I get the exact number of days after split?

Comment: 10-Jun-2016  31-Mar-2017  294
01-Apr-2017  31-Mar-2018  364
01-Apr-2018  31-Mar-2019  364
01-Apr-2019  09-Jun-2019  69

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow the question.  If I do, you're not counting the three days between your four buckets of days.  If there are 294 days between June 10, 2016 and March 31, 2017 then your next group of days would need to start on March 31 not April 1.  Otherwise, you don't count that day and you end up 3 short.

Comment: The difference you calculate in your date ranges looks 1 out - do you really expect a full year to only have 364 days? The total should probably be 1095 rather than 1094 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be counting the difference between the date limits, you should count the total days in the range. i.e. (Date 2 - Date 1 + 1) instead of (Date 2 - Date 1).

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
WITH date_ranges ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2016-06-10', DATE '2019-06-09' FROM DUAL
),
financial_years ( start_date, end_date, year_start ) AS (
  SELECT start_date,
         end_date,
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( ADD_MONTHS( start_date, -3 ), 'Y', 12 * LEVEL - 9 )
  FROM   date_ranges
  CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( ADD_MONTHS( start_date, -3 ), 'Y', 12 * LEVEL - 9 ) <= end_date
),
financial_year_ranges ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT GREATEST( start_date, year_start ),
         LEAST( end_date, ADD_MONTHS( year_start, 12 ) - 1 )
  FROM   financial_years
)
SELECT start_date,
       end_date,
       end_date - start_date + 1 AS num_days
FROM   financial_year_ranges;
```

**Output**:

```
START_DATE END_DATE   NUM_DAYS
---------- ---------- --------
2016-06-10 2017-03-31      295
2017-04-01 2018-03-31      365
2018-04-01 2019-03-31      365
2019-04-01 2019-06-09       70
```